# Origin Master Head Behind the Latest Pushed Commit

Tags: git, github

My git repo `my_package` is having an issue with HEAD pointing to the latest pushed commit. My local repo shows the HEAD at the latest commit `commit Z`. However, the origin shows that the master HEAD is behind the latest commit `commit Z` on master. To clarify, `commit Z` is visible on origin master, but the HEAD is on the previous commit, `commit Y`. `git pull origin master` says all changes are up to date, and I am unable to create a code review for merging as `my_package` is unmodified.

I want to make the origin and my local repo's HEADs at the same place -- at the latest commit, not before. How can I do this when history modification for the origin's master branch is disabled?

Thanks!

EDIT: I can't include a verbatim copy of the `git log` for privacy reasons, but when I run it locally it shows up as such:

```
commit abcdeID12345 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Jessica 
Date:   Mon Nov 8 10:37:09 2021 -0500

    commit Z

commit abcdeID12345
Author: Jessica
Date:   Wed Oct 13 14:06:55 2021 -0400

    commit Y
```

I want to highlight that this local log does not match the origin's, as described above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out your local branch and set your local branch to track the origin branch, and then just do a git pull as below:

```
git checkout master;
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master;
git pull;
```

If the problem still persists, check if the origin is pointing to the correct remote URL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I tried these commands, and still everything is up to date with no changes. The remote URL is the right one. Also, I'm confused at how this would fix the origin's HEAD location issue, as this only changes things in my local repo?

Comment: Can you share the `git log` command output in the question?

Comment: Just added it!!

Comment: `I want to make the origin and my local repo's HEADs at the same place`  This is what you need and what you have in the git log, right?

Comment: As per what I see in your logs, HEAD and origin/HEAD are on the same commit